# Carregar um arquivo html no laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

Eu tenho um site e preciso anexar a esse site uma pasta chamada processos onde, quando o usuario digitar `meu-site.com/processos` ou `meu-site.com/processos/index.html`, seja carregado o arquivo.Localmente eu consigo fazer isso inserindo a pasta processos na pasta public do projeto.Porem quando eu upo para o servidor dá a mensagem de eu não possuo permissão para a acessar a pasta public naquele servidor.Obrigado desde já

Eu tentei utilizar a seguinte rota:

```
Route::get('processos',function(){
    return Redirect::to('processos/index.html');
});
```

Porem não deu certo e não sei como chamar esse arquivo e onde essa pasta processos deve ficar no projeto, ja que é uma pasta externa.

Comment: Poste o seu arquivo e web.php da pasta rotas, por favor, irá ajudar na resposta

Answer (score -1):

Você pode criar uma pasta chamada **"html"** dentro de sua pasta **"public"** por exemplo, e fazer a chamada aos arquivos **HTML** como abaixo:

`Route::get('/processos', function () {
    return File::get(public_path() . '/html/index.html');
});`

Comment: Não deu certo, ele carrega o index.html mas não carrega os .html que o index linka

Comment: Você poderia mostrar como estão os links dentro do **'index.html'**?

Comment: <HTML>  
<HEAD>
 <TITLE> ARPO BPMN++ MODELER </TITLE>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 </HEAD>

 <FRAMESET ROWS='76,*'>
  <FRAME SRC='Frame_Header.html'>
 <FRAMESET  COLS='320,*'>
  <FRAME SRC='Frame_HTML_Level.html'>
  <FRAME SRC='Frame_Welcome.html' NAME='TARGET_ARPO'>
 </FRAMESET>

</HTML>